# Assignment of field in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I add a method to PictureBook model,

```
class PictureBook(models.Model):
    license = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    activate_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # check if the license is available.
    def activate(self, license=None):
        if self.activate_count != 2 and self.license == license:
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            self.activate_count += 1
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

then call `activate()` in `views.py`, I have added

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

then I see output,

```
-> self.activate_count += 1
(Pdb)
```

I type 'c', program continue. And I check the value `activate_count` in admin, it should be 1, but it still 0. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `self.save()` after you increase it, so that it actually saves your changes:

```
def activate(self, license=None):
        if self.activate_count != 2 and self.license == license:
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            self.activate_count += 1
            self.save()
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't save the model instance.